# Algorithm for generating all possible boolean functions of n variables

Tags: algorithm, boolean-logic

For n variables, there exists 2^(2^n) distinct boolean functions. For example, if n=2, then there exists 16 possible boolean functions which can be written in sum of product form, or product of sum forms. The number of possible functions increases exponentially with n.

I am looking for an algorithm which can generate all these possible boolean rules for n variables. I have tried to search at various places, but have not found anything suitable till now. Most of the algorithms are related to simplifying or reducing boolean functions to standard forms.

I know even for the number of rules become too large even for n=8 or 9, but can somebody please help me out with the relevant algorithm if it exists?

Comment: It's too large even for `n = 6`... For `n = 5` you can use bitmasks. There's a straightforward bijection between the integer range `0..(2^(2^n)-1)` and the boolean functions on `n` variables

Comment: You are right Niklas. I am just looking for a way to generate the boolean expressions which corresponds to these bijection and the boolean functions.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to build the [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) directly from the truth table. I'm not sure what your question is

Comment: My question is forming the disjunctive normal form without using the truth table. If possible, this approach should be faster than first making the truth table.

Comment: I don't think you realize what a "truth table" is in your scenario. It's just a 2^n-bit number. How is it not fast to increment this number in a loop to enumerate them all? In fact evaluating such a function for even a single assignment of variables is probably a lot slower than generating the truth table representation

Comment: @prabhat The truth table form is isomorphic to the algebraic disjunctive normal form (a sum of products). It is neither faster nor slower, those are just two different ways of writing the same thing.

Comment: I see. My confusion was getting driven by the issue that I am trying to find a way to discard many of the possible functions to limit my computing time. I am trying to compute all possible functions for 11 nodes, so looks like I will have to limit the number of input nodes eventually. Thanks all.

Comment: @prabhat There might be a way, but you explicitely asked how to enumerate all functions. Maybe you want to ask a different question about what you actually want to achieve

Comment: In Wolfram Mathematica: `Do[Print[BooleanMinimize[BooleanFunction[i, {x,y,z}]]], {i, 1, 255, 1}]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A boolean function of *n* variables has *2^n* possible inputs.  These can be enumerated by printing out the binary representation of values in the range `0 <= x < 2^n`.

For each one of the those possible inputs, a boolean function can output *0* or *1*.  To enumerate all the possibilities (i.e. every possible truth table).  List the binary values in range `0 <= x < 2^(2^n)`.

Here's the algorithm in Python:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import product       # forms cartesian products
n = 3                               # number of variables

print('All possible truth tables for n =', n)
inputs = list(product([0, 1], repeat=n))
for output in product([0, 1], repeat=len(inputs)):
    print()
    print('Truth table')
    print('-----------')
    for row, result in zip(inputs, output):
        print(row, '-->', result)
```

The output looks like this:

```
All possible truth tables for n = 3

Truth table
-----------
(0, 0, 0) --> 0
(0, 0, 1) --> 0
(0, 1, 0) --> 0
(0, 1, 1) --> 0
(1, 0, 0) --> 0
(1, 0, 1) --> 0
(1, 1, 0) --> 0
(1, 1, 1) --> 0

Truth table
-----------
(0, 0, 0) --> 0
(0, 0, 1) --> 0
(0, 1, 0) --> 0
(0, 1, 1) --> 0
(1, 0, 0) --> 0
(1, 0, 1) --> 0
(1, 1, 0) --> 0
(1, 1, 1) --> 1

Truth table
-----------
(0, 0, 0) --> 0
(0, 0, 1) --> 0
(0, 1, 0) --> 0
(0, 1, 1) --> 0
(1, 0, 0) --> 0
(1, 0, 1) --> 0
(1, 1, 0) --> 1
(1, 1, 1) --> 0

Truth table
-----------
(0, 0, 0) --> 0
(0, 0, 1) --> 0
(0, 1, 0) --> 0
(0, 1, 1) --> 0
(1, 0, 0) --> 0
(1, 0, 1) --> 0
(1, 1, 0) --> 1
(1, 1, 1) --> 1

... and so on
```

If you want the output in algebraic form rather than truth tables, the algorithm is the same:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import product       # forms cartesian products
n = 3                               # number of variables

variables = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[:n]
pairs = [('~'+var, var) for var in variables]
print('All possible algebraic expressions for n =', n)

inputs = list(product(*pairs))
for i, outputs in enumerate(product([0, 1], repeat=len(inputs))):
    terms = [''.join(row) for row, output in zip(inputs, outputs) if output]
    if not terms:
        terms = ['False']
    print('Function %d:' % i, ' or '.join(terms))
```

The output looks like this:

```
All possible algebraic expressions for n = 3
Function 0: False
Function 1: abc
Function 2: ab~c
Function 3: ab~c or abc
Function 4: a~bc
Function 5: a~bc or abc
Function 6: a~bc or ab~c
Function 7: a~bc or ab~c or abc
Function 8: a~b~c
Function 9: a~b~c or abc
Function 10: a~b~c or ab~c
Function 11: a~b~c or ab~c or abc
Function 12: a~b~c or a~bc
Function 13: a~b~c or a~bc or abc
Function 14: a~b~c or a~bc or ab~c
Function 15: a~b~c or a~bc or ab~c or abc
Function 16: ~abc
Function 17: ~abc or abc
Function 18: ~abc or ab~c
Function 19: ~abc or ab~c or abc
Function 20: ~abc or a~bc
Function 21: ~abc or a~bc or abc
Function 22: ~abc or a~bc or ab~c
Function 23: ~abc or a~bc or ab~c or abc
Function 24: ~abc or a~b~c
Function 25: ~abc or a~b~c or abc
Function 26: ~abc or a~b~c or ab~c
Function 27: ~abc or a~b~c or ab~c or abc
Function 28: ~abc or a~b~c or a~bc
Function 29: ~abc or a~b~c or a~bc or abc
Function 30: ~abc or a~b~c or a~bc or ab~c
Function 31: ~abc or a~b~c or a~bc or ab~c or abc
Function 32: ~ab~c
Function 33: ~ab~c or abc

... and so on
```

Comment: Surely this would be one way of doing it. But a more convenient way could be to directly generate a Boolean algebraic expression corresponding to each of the truth tables. This would help in much easier analysis if one intends to fit a given dataset using a boolean model. Any suggestions on this line? Thanks a lot.

Comment: FWIW, the truth tables map directly to algebraic expressions as a sum of products.  For example, the last truth table listed above can be written as: ``(ab~c) or (abc)``.  There is less magic to this than you imagine.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, there's a one-to-one relation between numbers and truth tables. For example, we can represent the truth table

```
0 0 0  | 1
0 0 1  | 1
0 1 0  | 0
0 1 1  | 0
1 0 0  | 1
1 0 1  | 0 
1 1 0  | 1
1 1 1  | 0
```

by the binary number `01010011` (the topmost row is represented by the least-significant bit).

It is obviously just a matter of looping over numbers to generate these representations:

```
for f := 0 to 2^(2^n) - 1:
    # do something with f
```

What can we do with `f`? We can evaluate it, for example. Say we want to know `f(0,1,0)`. It's as simple as interpreting the argument as the binary number `x = 010` and doing some bit-magic:

```
def evaluate(f, x):
    return (f & (1<<x)) != 0
```

We can also find its disjunctive normal form by just checking which bits are 0:

```
def dnf(f):
    for x := 0 to 2^n - 1:
        if f & (1<<x) != 0:
            print binary(x) + " OR "
```

Giving a result like `000 OR 001 OR 100 OR 110 (OR)` for the function above.

Comment: for an arbitary truth  table is dnf possible ?

Answer (score 3):

I've changed the code posted by Raymond Hettinger.
Now you can:

1. generate all Boolean expressions up to n_ary,
2. pick a particular function,
3. perform evaluation, and
4. get answers in binary or True/False manner.

Code:

```
    from itertools import product

    def allBooleanFunctions(kk):
        """Finds all Boolean functions for indegree kk"""
        inputs1 = list(product([0, 1], repeat=kk))
        variables = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[:kk]
        pairs = [('( not '+var+' )', var) for var in variables]
        inputs = list(product(*pairs))

        bool_func=[]

        for i, outputs in enumerate(product([0, 1], repeat=len(inputs))):
            terms = [' and '.join(row) for row, output in zip(inputs, outputs) if output]
            if not terms:
                terms = ['False'] 
            bool_func.append(('('+(') or ('.join(terms))+')'))
        return bool_func

    n_ary=2 # number of inputs; keep it n_ary<=5

    boolean_function_analytical=allBooleanFunctions(n_ary)

    print('All Boolean functions of indegree:'+str(n_ary)+'\n')
    print(boolean_function_analytical)
    print
    print('A Boolean function:'+'\n')
    print(boolean_function_analytical[2])
    # Evaluate third boolean function:
    a=1 # first input
    b=0 # second input
    c=0 # third input
    d=0 # fourth input
    print('a='+str(a)+'; b='+str(b)+'; c='+str(c)+'; d='+str(d)+'\n')
    print('Evaluation in 0/1 manner:')
    print(int(eval((boolean_function_analytical[2]))))
    print('Evaluation in True/False manner:')
    print(bool(eval((boolean_function_analytical[2]))))
```

Result:

```
    All Boolean functions of indegree:2

    ['(False)', '(a and b)', '(a and ( not b ))', '(a and ( not b )) or (a and b)', '(( not a ) and b)', '(( not a ) and b) or (a and b)', '(( not a ) and b) or (a and ( not b ))', '(( not a ) and b) or (a and ( not b )) or (a and b)', '(( not a ) and ( not b ))', '(( not a ) and ( not b )) or (a and b)', '(( not a ) and ( not b )) or (a and ( not b ))', '(( not a ) and ( not b )) or (a and ( not b )) or (a and b)', '(( not a ) and ( not b )) or (( not a ) and b)', '(( not a ) and ( not b )) or (( not a ) and b) or (a and b)', '(( not a ) and ( not b )) or (( not a ) and b) or (a and ( not b ))', '(( not a ) and ( not b )) or (( not a ) and b) or (a and ( not b )) or (a and b)']

    A Boolean function:

    (a and ( not b ))
    a=1; b=0; c=0; d=0

    Evaluation in 0/1 manner:
    1
    Evaluation in True/False manner:
    True
```

Have fun!!!