# Technical Term for this Rule Combination Pattern

Tags: logic

I've been working on a program that takes a list of rules and tests combinations of them to operate a simple controller. The rules can only be true.

One rule would generate one controller:

```
A: If Cond1 Then True

If A then Activate
```

Two rules can generate 2 controllers:

```
A: If Cond1 Then True
B: If Cond2 Then True

If A and B then Activate
If A or B then Activate
```

Three rules generate 8 controllers:

```
A: If Cond1 Then True
B: If Cond2 Then True
C: If Cond3 Then True

A and B and C
A or B or C
(A and B) or C
A or (B and C)
(A and C) or B
(A and B) or (A and C)
(B and C) or (A and C)
(A and B) or (B and C)
```

Is there a formal name for this procedure? What field of study does this type of program fall under? All I've been able to find is that each controller might be described as using "fuzzy logic".

Comment: This isn't fuzzy logic.  It sounds like you just want to generate all distinct logic expressions (involving AND and OR) for N inputs.

Comment: Note that `(A and B) or (A and C) == A and (B or C)`.

Answer (score 0):

Truth tables exist for each of the controllers in the questions. The desired output could be obtained by filtering the output of a program that generated truth tables.

More about generating truth tables here:
[Algorithm for generating all possible boolean functions of n variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600552/algorithm-for-generating-all-possible-boolean-functions-of-n-variables)