# Why bitshift when evaluating truth tables as binary numbers?

Tags: binary, truthtable

The last answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22601653/1115655) shows that a binary truth table can be represented as a binary number:

```
0 0 0  | 1
0 0 1  | 1
0 1 0  | 0
0 1 1  | 0
1 0 0  | 1
1 0 1  | 0 
1 1 0  | 1
1 1 1  | 0
```

Can be represented by `01010011`.

The entries in the table can also be evaluated using this number.

```
def evaluate(f, x):
    return (f & (1<<x)) != 0

f = int('01010011',2)

>>> evaluate(f,int('100',2))
True
>>> evaluate(f,int('101',2))
False
```

My question is about the `evaluate` function provided by the answer. Why must we left shift the bits by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it backwards. It is the binary number 1 shifted left by `x` spots.

And that should make sense. If you want to check the 4th spot in the table, represented by `f`, you have to check that `f & 10000!=0`.

You're right, shifting by one is very arbitrary and does not make sense.